# miktex - update and (re)install previously installed packages

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I would like to update my MikTeX 2.9 portable. 
I originally installed it in 2011.

What I'd like to do is:

1. Get a list of packages installed in the old System
2. Install a new System somewhere
3. Use my list of previously installed packages to automatically install the current versions of them in the new System (from an updated file repository).

Is there some kinda "Package Manager Utility" that can do this?

Comment: I don't have a portable version of MiKTeX, but doesn't it have a MiKTeX Package Manager (to have the list of installed packages, and their installation date) and MiKTeX Updater, just like the installled version?

Comment: The portable version of MiKTeX comes with it packages manger!

Comment: @Bernard - I didn't notice that there is a command line Version of the Package Manager - thanks for the hint.

Comment: @OL - I didn't notice that there is a command line Version of the Package Manager - thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just posting this answer to close this question.

Thanks to Bernard and OL I went back to the documentation and noticed that there is a command line version of the Package Manager that does what I want. Give them clicks if you find this helpful.